# pop up window does not open when code added in java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a contact form that will appear when a button is clicked. This works fine. However, when I add js-code to close the contact via a button inside the contact form it won't open at all.

I think it's a problem with the logic, but I can't locate where. Syntax seems fine.

Be aware that the js code which renders everything useless has been commented out. I have added it in the descriptions, so it should hopefully be clear for anyone to make head and tales out of it. Also, you must click on the window to make the contact form appear because the display in css is set to 'none' and changes upon clicking to 'flex'.

```js
//this function will make the contact-form open upon clicking the "get a quote" Button
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let quoteButton = document.getElementById('quote-button');
 let contactWrapper = document.getElementById('contact-wrapper');
  
  if (contactWrapper.style.display == 'none') {
    contactWrapper.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    (contactWrapper.style.display = 'none');
  }
});

//this function shoud make the contact-form disappear upon clicking the "Back" Button, however above code (to make contact form appear) does not work if bellow code is enabled.

/*
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let backbutton = document.getElementById('back-button');
  let contactWrapper = document.getElementById('contact-wrapper');
 
    if (contactWrapper.style.display == 'flex') {
      contactWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    } 
});
*/


//this function will make the contact-form stick in place when opened
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-wrapper');
  let maxTopYPosition = 0;
  let maxBottomYPosition = 4000;
  
  if (window.pageYOffset >= maxTopYPosition && window.pageYOffset < maxBottomYPosition) {
    contactForm.classList.add('sticky-contact-wrapper');
  } else {
    contactForm.classList.remove('sticky-contact-wrapper');
  }
});
```

```css
/*   Beginning of Contact-Form
     The contact form is only visible on click*/
  #contact-wrapper {
  display: none;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 10000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.975), rgba(173, 173, 173, 0.975), rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.975), rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.975), rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.975));
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px rgb(206, 197, 197, 0.5); 
}

.sticky-contact-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10vh;
  opacity: 1;
 animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 2vh 2vw;
}

.flex-item1 {
  flex-grow: 7;
}

.flex-item2 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  display: flex;
}

#contact-form p {
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 2vh 0 6px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#contact-form .input-field {
  height: 5vh;
  width: 80%;
}

#contact-form .message-field{
  height: 12vh;
}

.button-flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#contact-form button {
  display: block;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 10vw;
  min-width: 75px;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(173, 66, 66);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dropZone {
  width: 33vw;
  height: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  line-height: -50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.dropZone h3 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: rgb(235, 231, 231);
  height: 200px; width:200px;
  color: black;
}

.dropZone.dragover {
  border-color: black;
  color: #000;
}

/* End of contact form */
```

```html
 <!--  CONTACT-FORM  -->
      <div id="contact-wrapper">
          <div class="flex-item flex-item1">
            <form id="contact-form" action="" method="POST" 
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <p>Name</p>
              <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="name">
              <p>Last Name</p>
              <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="name">
              <p>work email</p>
              <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="email">
              <p>phone</p>
              <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="phone">
              <p>message</p>
              <input class="input-field message-field" type="text">
              <br><br>
              <p>Submit your request</p>
              <br>
              <div class="button-flex-wrapper">
                <div>
                <button id="back-button" type="button">Back</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                <button id="submit-button" type="button">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="uploads" class="flex-item flex-item2">
            <div class="dropZone" id="dropZone">
              <h3>Drop Files Here</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: *Be aware that the js code which renders everything useless has been commented out.* You mean omitted. We can't help you if you don't show us your code. And, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites. Post it right here with your question as a "code snippet".

Comment: Maybe we can all give this guy a few minutes to add his codepen link before we downvote him into oblivion.

Comment: @BryanDowning There shouldn't be a codepen in the first place.

Comment: I'll add code here. But why not code pen?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with hosting a demo on code pen, but a [mcve] needs to be in the question itself, and since Stackoverflow supports live demos, having another one on a third party site is usually redundant.

Comment: `if (contactWrapper.style.display = 'flex') {` — Off-topic. Typo. That's an assignment, not a comparison. Get the number of `=` correct.

Comment: @Dan From [ask]: "_If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time._"

Comment: Changed:
if (contactWrapper.style.display = 'flex')
to 
if (contactWrapper.style.display == 'flex')
still does not work

Comment: Should I add the rest of the code?

Comment: Posting to a 3rd party site is discouraged for a couple of reasons. 1) 3rd party links can die over time and then your question is meaningless to anyone who comes across it. Remember, Stack Overflow is a knowledge base - it's not just for you to get your answer, it's for others in the future. 2) It's often unnecessary since Stack Overflow provides the ability to include "code snippets", which are executable chunks of code just like JSFiddle or Codepen.

Comment: will keep this in mind, you are right.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, the problem was that the event handler was listening for any kind of click event in the window object. Instead I refactored the code and put the respective buttons in variables and added the addEventListener.

```js
// contact-form opens upon clicking the "get a quote" Button

let quoteButton = document.getElementById('quote-button');

quoteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
 let contactWrapper = document.getElementById('contact-wrapper');
  if (contactWrapper.style.display == 'none') {
    contactWrapper.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    (contactWrapper.style.display = 'none');
  }
});

//contact-form disapears when clicking "back" Button

let backbutton = document.getElementById('back-button');

backbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let contactWrapper = document.getElementById('contact-wrapper');
    if (contactWrapper.style.display == 'flex') {
      contactWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JS is just listening for any 'click' right now, that seems to be the problem. You should add an onclick handler to your button via your html and have that perform the JS function.

```
<button onclick="openContactForm()" id="quote-button">Open Contact</button>
```

I turned your code into a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/QJzwVj) so you and others can check it out and provide some additional input. I also made the changes I spoke about in it for you.

Comment: After sleeping over the issue this came to my mind as well. I think you got a down vote because the inline onclick attribute is discouraged. After researching a bit, I think good practice would have been to get the event in the way described in my own answer. Thx for your input though.